Method of proof of $x^y<x^z$ if $1<x$,$y<z$
Is it valid to prove this statement with this method assuming that If $x>1$ $x^p<x^q$ when p<q and p and q are rational
Statement: $x^y<x^z$ if $1<x$,$y<z$; \
Attempt:
Take the dedekind cut A and B associated with y and z respectively, given that y<z, there exist an element b such that b$\in$B and an upper bound of A. Let the dedekind cut associated with $x^y$ & $x^z$ be $A_x$ and $B_x$ respectively.
Let b be such b, as b is an upper bound of A
$\forall a\in A \in B |b>a$
$\implies \forall a\in A \exists b\in B |x^b>x^a $ By the assumed statement
Then, as $x^b \in B_x $ then $sup(B_x) \geq x^b > sup(A_x)$
(^ Above is the statement in doubt)
Therefore, $sup(A_x) = x^y < x^z = sup(B_x)$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

It is not clear what your " but an upper bound in A" means, and how it justifies "$\forall a\in A \exists b\in B |b>a$".
